# Ipad Interface Orientation Problem

Tags: ipad, animation, uiview, landscape, portrait

For the moment I test my application on the simulator.
I have an appDelegate and in this delegate I have several controllers that I want to use.
The First one, that I display, is a view which show that the application is loading. 
And when it's loaded I want to display another view. To display this new view I use an animation but it doesn't work well. In fact during the animation the new view is display in a portrait mode and when the animation finishes it move to a landscape mode.
Nevertheless in my info.plist I allow landscape only and in all my .xib file all of my view are in landscape mode.

So I don't understand why this animation keep on displaying my view in a portrait mode.

Have Someone an idea about this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to show the animation too early. You shouldn't be driving this process from the app delegate. Your initial interface should load by way of a UIViewController that provides the root view. When that UIViewController gets didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: for the first time, the interface has finished loading and rotating into landscape mode and you're ready to rock and roll.